# line break i #each#command

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I have a html file that gets data from an .js file with #each command like this:

```
{{#each ssarr ../Maxss this}}
        <td>{{this}}</td>
        {{/each}}
```

that output the data in a long line.
Is it in some way possible to make a linebreak after 10 values so the row does not be so long?

Comment: Is this all ? Do you have any HTML surrounding this with table, tr etc?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit surprised by the syntax of the each loop, try using a custom helper like this one :

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('each_limit', function(array, min, max, options) {
    if(!array || array.length == 0) return options.inverse(this);
    var result = [];
    for(var i = (min!==null?min:0); i < (max!==null?max:array.length) && i < array.length; ++i)
        result.push(options.fn(array[i]));
    return result.join('');

});
```

You may also take a look to this answer : [Handlebars - Not each but some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48869700/handlebars-not-each-but-some/48882936#48882936)